# NetSuite Error Configuration - How can you help it out?

Tags: netsuite

The Same setups works for other clients' configuration except for one particular client and this is the error message...

NetSuite

== soap xml response ==
    403 Forbidden

## Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /services/NetSuitePort_2019_1on this server.

]]>
== end ==

Can anyone help ? How to resolve this !

403 Forbidden

## Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /services/NetSuitePort_2019_1on this server.

]]>